# Connecting more than 2 monitors to PC

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

What are possible ways to connect more than two monitors to my PC?

I know two ways:

1. graphic card with more than two video slots
2. two graphic cards to support more than two video slots.

But what about USB->VGA,DVI,HDMI converter, I read that this problem can be solved on this way, but have some disadvantages, what are disadvantages of this way?

Comment: Using Converter Cables is not an efficient way but it does work. It's unreliable because the cables won't handle all the data sent over them. Having a Graphic card to connect multiple monitor is good because the CPU in Graphic Card handles all data processing.

Comment: USB options can sometimes be expensive, are you using a laptop or desktop? I would assume desktop due to mentioning GPU options. If so it would be cheaper to get a GPU than a USB option 9 times out of 10. If your using a laptop look at a USB docking station which will allow you to have multiple monitors running through USB.

Comment: Its a really broad question. I'm not really inclined to throw the moderator closevote of doom on it, but I suspect its likely to be closed. Most of the converters you're talking about simply turn one output to another, it dosen't add new outputs.

Comment: A usb graphics devices won't be fast enough to play action games on this monitor. But if you "only" want to display text or perhaps even movies there are USB 3.0 graphic cards that are reported to be fast enough.